# Repairing git after mercurial import

Tags: git, mercurial

Some time ago I have moved my project from my self-hosted mercurial repository to the github.

Now it seems, that I didn't check the result of the import process carefully enough. I have ended with some commits with no parents set.

For example, look at commit [fbf4e876f172e7a4a03153b801bd44cf71d98601](https://github.com/umlfri/umlfri2/commit/fbf4e876f172e7a4a03153b801bd44cf71d98601). It has no parent and contains all files with all content, as if it would be the initial commit. But when I look into my original hg repository, this commit should have one parent - [c1b215a3ae19dd9b6771a4ffe9217d6f9b65d4a9](https://github.com/umlfri/umlfri2/commit/c1b215a3ae19dd9b6771a4ffe9217d6f9b65d4a9).

Is there any way to reparent the invalid commits? I need to use git blame some times and it gives me useless results now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you haven't done any work with the new Git repository and still have the original Mercurial repository, your best bet might be to re-convert with whatever commands and/or options result in a correct conversion.  Then you need not worry about missing anything.

If that fails, well:

> Is there any way to reparent the invalid commits?

Sort of, yes.  But also no.  Consider using `git replace` to make initial repairs, and then `git filter-branch` to rewrite the repository (after which all users must switch to the rewritten one).

#### Replacements

Fundamentally, the problem is that no commit can ever be changed.  A commit can be *copied* to a new, somewhat-different commit that is otherwise "just as good as" the original commit, and this is one way to deal with the problem.

Git has the ability to "replace" commits (or indeed any Git object), using [the `git replace` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-replace.html).  The way this works under the covers is that the "replaced" commit remains in the repository intact, in its original form, and you make a new replacement object, usually by copying-but-changing-slightly the original object (although you can [construct a new one from whole cloth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40341/where-does-the-idiom-whole-cloth-come-from) if you like).  This replacement object goes into the repository, with a special external name of the form `refs/replace/<hash-id>`.  Whenever Git goes to look up and use the original object by its hash ID, it first checks to see if a `refs/replace/<id>` reference exists.  If so, Git turns its eyes away from the original object to the replacement.  The front end `git replace` command makes this process much less painful, but there is one big caveat: *Replacement objects are not normally transferred across clones.*  This includes both initial clones and fetch operations.

(They *can* be, it's not that hard, but it's not the default.  This is for various good reasons, specifically including security.  Whatever security one gains from PGP-signing tags and/or commits is instantly lost if replacements are allowed.  If you have direct access to the repository, so that you can run `git replace`, you are already pretty much independent of cryptographic security; but if you clone or fetch, you depend on it.)

#### Filter-branch

The `git filter-branch` command is all about copying commits, with some changes (filters) applied along the way.  After copying some set of commits ending with the commit to which some branch name or other reference points, the `filter-branch` command rewrites the reference to point to the new copied chain.

If a copy of a commit is bit-for-bit identical to its original, the copy actually *is* the original.  Only commits that change in some way result in new copies (with different hash IDs).  The filter-branch code still copies every commit, but some copies wind up being "free" this way.

Consider this tiny, four-commit repository:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Let's say the filter introduces a change to commit `C` so that it becomes commit `C'` instead, which means Git must also copy commit `D` to `D'`, with the difference between `D` and `D'` being that `D'` links back to `C'`.  The filtered repository then contains:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- refs/original/refs/heads/master
    \
     C'-D'   <-- master
```

If you specify no filters at all, Git simply copies each commit.  If you use `--all --tag-name-filter cat`, Git applies this process to all branches and all tags.  But—this is the key—the copying *uses the replacements.*  So, let's draw your own repository, including the incorrect commit `fbf4e876f172e7a4a03153b801bd44cf71d98601` (let's call this `F` for short) and a replacement `F'` that has the correct parent `c1b215a3ae19dd9b6771a4ffe9217d6f9b65d4a9` (let's call this `C` for short):

```
...--C--...  <-- refs/heads/somebranch
      \
       F'    <-- refs/replace/F

F            <--- tag: v2.0.0
```

(commit `F` has no parent so it just sits there as a second root commit).

We now run `git replace --all --tag-name-filter cat`, so Git finds all commits reachable from all references, including `refs/heads/somebranch` and `refs/tags/v2.0.0`.  So it copies commits before and after `C` but there are no changes to them.  It goes to copy `F` but switches to the replacement `F'`, and copies `F'` which has no change to it either.

Now that it has copied everything (except `F`) it makes the names, `refs/heads/somebranch` and `refs/tags/v2.0.0`, point to the copies.  This has no effect on `somebranch`, but makes `refs/tags/v2.0.0` point to the replacement commit `F'`.

The filter-branch code adds `refs/original/` names to retain the original branch tips and tagged commits, so there is a `refs/original/refs/heads/somebranch` and `refs/original/refs/tags/v2.0.0`, which you will discard.

The easiest way to do this is, usually, to clone the filtered repository: this clone does not pick up the `refs/replace/` references, and also does not pick up the `refs/original/` references.  It gets only the `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` references.  (There are several other ways to do this, if you don't like the clone method.  Most of them leave the extra copies of commits in the repository for at least 30 days, until they expire naturally and get garbage-collected.  If you're only replacing a few commits, this is not that big a deal.)